# How to set column values as column name in pl SQL but I don't know what what will be the column values?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to populate few aa.one, aa.two, aa.three columns from aa table and when I put aa.one = 'abc' in where condition  I want to rename these column names as column values will populate. But one thing I don't know what value will populate through out the table

Comment: Can you provide us with sample data? Your current work, an example, your table, your expected result...
Please put some effort into it. We can not write your work for you, merely help you with an issue.

Answer (score 0):

The only way out is `dynamic SQL` as you have to *compose* the whole statement dynamically and run it using `execute immediate`.

Note that it is difficult to maintain; might be OK for very simple cases, but for complex queries ... I'd think **twice** before actually doing something about it.

Something like this:

```
declare
  l_str varchar2(200);
begin
  l_str := 'update '    || par_table_name     || ' set ' ||
           par_column_1 || ' = ' || par_value_1          ||
           ' where '    || par_column_where_1 || ' = '   || par_column_where_value_1;

  execute immediate l_str;
end;
```